# Chain Retrofit calls for authorization and subsequent calls using RxJava

Tags: android, authorization, rx-java, retrofit2, chain

I am a new with Rxjava. I want to capture access token (received as part of headers) from the response of the first api call and then use that access token (as header) for subsequent api calls.

Note: the in the first api call, the response has no body,only headers are returned.

My Network Interface:

```
public interface NetworkInterface {

@POST("https://appauth.treuspan/Login")
Observable<Response<Void>> getAuthDetails(
        @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
        @Body AuthRequestDetails authRequestDetails
        );

@POST("https://appauth.treuspan//storedetails")
Observable<StoreDetailsResponse> getStoreDetails(
        @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
        @Header("Accept") String accept,
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Body AuthRequestBody authRequestBody
        );
}
```

My observable methods:

```
    public Observable<Response<Void>> getAuthObservable() {

    return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
            .getAuthDetails("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    new AuthRequestDetails().getAuthRequestDetails())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response<Void>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<Void> voidResponse) {
                    String access_token_received = voidResponse.headers().get("access_token");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

The above doesn't compile. Its compile says:

```
Incompatible type:
required: io.reactivex.Observable<retrofit2.Response<java.lang.Void>>
Found:    void
```

If I am able to successfully make the above call then i have to use the access token as part of header in the subsequent call as follows

```
public Observable<StoreDetailsResponse> getStoreDetailsObservable() {
    return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
            .getStoreDetails("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "application/json",
                    "Bearer access_token_received",
                    new AuthRequestBody().getAuthRequestBody())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<StoreDetailsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(StoreDetailsResponse response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
}
```

The above code also doesn't compile. It says:

```
Incompatible type:
required: io.reactivex.Observable<com.example.androidtest.model.StoreDetailsResponse>
Found:    void
```

Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subscribe(...) will return a Subscription
Try to edit your code, make method return a Subscription like this

```
    public Subscription getAuthObservable() {

        return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
            .getAuthDetails("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    new AuthRequestDetails().getAuthRequestDetails())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response<Void>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<Void> voidResponse) {
                    String access_token_received = voidResponse.headers().get("access_token");
                }
            });
      }
```

Comment: Still it doesnt compile, it says.Required: org.reactivestreams.Subscription Found: void

Comment: import  rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions.Subscription. try to edit getStoreDetailsObservable method.

Comment: import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions.Subscription. It is not Compiling, Other imports look like io.reactivex.Observable. Am using Android rx, does it make any difference. Thanks

Comment: Ok , if i follow your suggestion, observeOn doesn't compile now

Comment: ^^ contact telegram BananaDried, i will help you